# How can I get the Rails 5.2 asset pipeline to use relative paths for fonts/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My rails asset pipeline is compiling assets to use

> https://accounts.example.com/assets/fonts/foo.wott

when compiled instead of

> /assets/fonts/foo.wott

So when I am on my test domain I get CORS issues and well the asset is missing since it does not exist. In addition to this I am trying to move the assets to their on CDN so have configured my asset_host to be cdn.example.com which I would have hoped the assets would use.

I would like to know what methods I should look for that could possibly be overriding my intentions.

Comment: `src: url(asset_path('/fonts/foo.wott'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is to use relative paths. There are a few places where you may be setting a different host:

1. In your config files (e.g. `/config/environments/production.rb` or `config/application.rb`) you can set `config.action_controller.asset_host` or `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` (though the latter is primarily used in links).
2. Also in config files, you can set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` which sets the host for ActionMailer view helpers.
3. In `config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb` you can set the default `http_host` for the renderer attached to all of your controllers.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot though it turned out it was compiling the assets using prod when i needed stage... well in the end i needed to compile the assets twice per docker image so the image would be portable.